# Make the next viewcontroller partially visible via UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

Is it possible to make the "Next" `Viewcontroller` partially visible via `UIPageViewController` implementation?

Attached is the screenshot of AppStore and you can see that the "next image" is partially visible in the current controller index.

[image: sybview partially shown]

I have seen other implementation of the `UIPageViewController`, but the subview is always display in fullsize.

[image: sybview shown in fullsize]

Comment: The images are no longer showing up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with UIScrollView controller. See this [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content) it's great tutorial how to do exactly what you want.

Comment: I've started another thread to add functionalities to the above question. I'm hoping you can take a look. Thanks.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23173641/content-scroll-vertically-paging-scroll-horizontally

Comment: The tutorial doesn't show 'exactly' what was asked.